# How calculate weighting factors in order to perform weighted average of a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, weighted-average

Imagine we have a dataframe of 5 columns. These columns represent temperature values of different climate models. Also we have 1 vector that has the true values of the observations. I want to create a multi-model. There are 2 ways to go:

1st way --> just find the average of the 5 columns
2nd way --> find the weighted average of the 5 columns

My question is how can I calculate the weights for each model? I mean I can substract the temperature of a model with the temperature of the observations and find which model is closer to the real value, either by using absolute mean error or squared mean error to see which models should have a bigger weight. But is there a way that python can calculate the most appropriate weights?

Comment: Isn't the definition of the weighting the main aspect of designing your multi-model? Python can be used to calculate (do the math) but you have to define how the weighting should be done. Even if you use a standard method from some package you have to verify that this particular weighting makes sense in your application.

Comment: @jacob , thank you for your reply! I am just wondering if there is a standard method on how to calculate the weights, or do I just put values of my discretion as weights? I was wondering if there is a way to find the optimal weights let s say

Comment: But optimal with respect to what measure? I mean in your example you have 5 different estimated temperatures, lets assume you want to trust model `B` more since its predictions were better in the past. In this case you can weight the current prediction by 50:25:12.5:6.25:6.25 %. However, this is absolute arbitray since I have no clue how _much_ more you trust model `B`. Lets assume I propose two approaches for weighting, how would you evalute which is optimal?